# How to setup a small office network with Ubuntu as server and Windows machines as clients

Tags: networking, server, windows, samba

I wish to know how to setup a file and printer sharing network for a small office (10 computers with Windows OS). I would like to have Ubuntu in the role of file, printer and proxy server.

In my search I came across many suggestions about using Samba and a lot of configuration files such as /etc/samba/smb.conf, /etc/hosts file, /etc/resolv.conf, /etc/nsswitch.conf. It's a bit intimidating. But I am prepared to learn and practice. So I need guidance to understand how I can achieve what I wish to achieve. I know basics of networking, shell commands, file system navigation and vi.

Also, any suggestions for reading material will also be great help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you even tried looking for any documentation; the first three using a search engine were https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html.en https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way! and https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#0  (I added site:\*.ubuntu.com so as to get only official doco in startpage)

Comment: Yep, like I said, I did try the search engines. But the links you have so kindly provided did not turn up (at least with DuckDuckGo). But many thanks for providing the links. I can't wait to go through them and post back here if I run into problems. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: :)   I also use duckduckgo and it can use the same site: restriction to avoid unofficial stuff (which can be good, but can also be a drain).  Most documentation is wiki.ubuntu.com (where you want to check bottom right to see last person who edited it & how long ago; this isn't simple as some could be long ago due to few changes in what is documented, whilst other subjects change often & long-ago is a warning!).  The last big changes in samba were a result of WannaCry. The help & tutorials.ubuntu.com are just more wiki's (that usually require privileges to edit so in theory more trustworthy).